# Find all reflexicons using roman numerals

Tags: code-golf, roman-numerals

A reflexicon is a self-descriptive word list that describes its own letter counts. Take for example the one found by Ed Miller in 1985 in English:

> Sixteen e’s, six f’s, one g, three h’s, nine i’s, nine n’s, five o’s, five r’s, sixteen s’s, five t’s, three u’s, four v’s, one w, four x’s

This reflexicon contains exactly what it says it does as per the definition. These are pretty computationally intensive but your job is to find all the possible reflexicons using roman numerals; there are way fewer letters involved (`I V X L C D M`) which is why the search space is reduced. Notice the English reflexicon containing "one g" - we can call it "dummy text" and it is allowed. Our reduced alphabet only contains letters used in numerals. A reflexicon using roman numerals would be of the form:

> XII I, IV V, II X

The counts (12 I's, 4 V's, 2 X's) are not correct - this just illustrates the format (notice no plural `'s`). A letter is completely omitted if its count is 0 (there is no `L` in this case).

Here is a list of roman numerals [1..40] for convenience (doubtful you need any more than this):

```
I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X
XI XII XIII XIV XV XVI XVII XVIII XIX XX
XXI XXII XXIII XXIV XXV XXVI XXVII XXVIII XXIX XXX
XXXI XXXII XXXIII XXXIV XXXV XXXVI XXXVII XXXVIII XXXIX XL
```

These are all valid reflexicons (but these are not all!):

> IV I, II V

> V I, I L, II V, I X

> V I, II V, I X, I L

Standard `code-golf` rules apply - find all reflexicons using roman numerals! One per line

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you include a few examples of valid reflexicons in the post. [Here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/3zNMwVNHwdNTIYwLzgKSChEgwocrzBNZ0BlE@AIFPVGEfUCEy///AA) are some that should be valid to my understanding.

Comment: How strict is the output format? Is printing nested lists like `[["IV", "I"], ["II", "V"]]` fine?

Comment: @ovs The output format is strict, as per the examples. `IV I, II V` in that case

Comment: For future challenges, please consider relaxing your I/O format. There's a reason why cumbersome I/O formats is [the most upvoted thing to avoid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/58563).

Comment: @Arnauld I have to think about it in the future; I honestly can't tell right now what's more fair; I know formatting is the least interesting bit and some langs make it easier/harder but then it should be considered when the language is chosen; this is probably a discussion for another time/place

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 84 bytes

```
≔⪪”{⊞‴ΣAº⧴θπ⪪λpＡz” θΦＥ×¹⁶φ⪫Φ⁺Ｅ⮌↨﹪κφχ∧λ⁺⁺§θλ §IVXμＥ⮌↨÷κφ²×λ⁺I §LCDMμλ, ∧κ⁼﹪κφＩ⭆XVI№ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDNasMwDL7vKYRPMniQ7LBLT1m6gccCZR2hV9OYzsy1m9gJe3tPTppRqC3pIL4/dPxWw9Erm1IVgjk53F@sichAgsxF3QJ9STU3LQ5MAAPGBfR887AbjIv4ZmzUAzbqgl/mrAOWzwLKoigI9e6NWwE7O4YZ9aknPQSNL4pG47vRevz5p5QFp1m5Dq2AmTOPKkrX6V/sBVi@hliXTLY52Zln6p2FdHFrJtPpG5enjFzirjZMAruR/Ki3zVWTXz3FYkrRSOi1H5UN9/lrFSLuI53mlJOwQyuJWPuRTmWy0PI2KaXHyf4B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪”{⊞‴ΣAº⧴θπ⪪λpＡz” θ
```

Split the compressed string  `I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX` on spaces. Since there are only seven different Roman numerals, an description string can only have `22` of any one letter. However, this means that the letters `L`, `C`, `D` and `M` can only appear once, limiting the number to just `14` `I`s in the description string. I'm not convinced that you can actually get above `9` `I`s, and using base `10` makes the following loop somewhat golfier.

```
ΦＥ×¹⁶φ⪫Φ⁺Ｅ⮌↨﹪κφχ∧λ⁺⁺§θλ §IVXμＥ⮌↨÷κφ²×λ⁺I §LCDMμλ, ∧κ⁼﹪κφＩ⭆XVI№ιλ
```

Get the base `10` digits of the numbers up to `1000`, then use base `2` for the higher order bits, generate the description string represented by the number, count the number of times each Roman numeral appears, treat the digits as base `10`, and output those description strings where this equals the original number. Note that I don't have to count the number of occurrences of `L`, `D`, `C` and `M` since they will always appear the correct number of times and only exist to inflate the count of `I`s.

Comment: @ovs correct; I will add a clarification

Comment: @ovs Better now?

Comment: @Neil Yes that is as many as I found

Comment: Note that there are also at most 4 `V` and 4 `X`, which means at most 2 `X`, which means at most 13 `I` and 3 `V`, which means at most 3 total `X` and `V`, which means at most 10 `I`.  Also, `X` and `IX` don't have enough `I`s to reach those numbers.

Comment: Okay, so `IX` is actually possible (I keep forgetting to count the letter itself and not just the numbers.)  The rest should still hold.

Comment: @Nitrodon Thanks, it's good to know that base 10 is necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

Quite inefficient version that only finds the first reflexicon in 60 seconds.

```
₂ENÝ7ãDONQÏεŽ6ˆ.XRøʒ¬Ā}©.XDS{®ø`×S{Qiðý„, ý,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVUAqv9vc2FiaWX//@KCgkVOw503w6NET05Rw4/OtcW9NsuGLlhSw7jKksKsxIB9wqkuWERTe8Kuw7hgw5dTe1Fpw7DDveKAniwgw70s////LS1uby1sYXp5)

The builtin `.X` (*Convert from integer to roman numeral string*) does help quite a bit.

**Commented**:

```
₂E                 # for N in 1 .. 26:
  NÝ               #   range from 0 to N
    7ã             #   7th cartesian power - all 7-tuples with values in [0..N]
      DONQÏ        #   keep those that sum to N
  ε                #   map over the tuples                                       example: [4,2,0,0,0,0,0]
   Ž6ˆ             #     compressed integer 1666                                  [4,2,0,0,0,0,0], 1666
      .XR          #     convert to Roman numeral and reverse                     [4,2,0,0,0,0,0], "IVXLCDM"
         ø         #     zip this string with the current tuple                   [[4,"I"],[2,"V"],[0,"X"],[0,"L"],[0,"C"],[0,"D"],[0,"M"]]
          ʒ¬Ā}     #     keep only the pairs with a number larger than 0          [[4,"I"],[2,"V"]]
   ©               #     store the list in the register                           [[4,"I"],[2,"V"]]
    .X             #     convert all numbers in the list to Roman numerals        [["IV","I"],["II","V"]]
      f            #     make a copy of the resulting list ...                    [["IV","I"],["II","V"]], [["IV","I"],["II","V"]]
       S{          #     ... and flatten and sort it                              [["IV","I"],["II","V"]], ["I","I","I","I","V","V"]
         ®         #     get the list with the integers still in it               [["IV","I"],["II","V"]], ["I","I","I","I","V","V"], [[4,"I"],[2,"V"]]
          ø`×      #     and repeat Roman digit the corresponding number of times [["IV","I"],["II","V"]], ["I","I","I","I","V","V"], ["IIII","VV"]
              S{   #     flatten and sort this                                    [["IV","I"],["II","V"]], ["I","I","I","I","V","V"], ["I","I","I","I","V","V"]
                Q  #     are the two sorted lists of characters equal?            [["IV","I"],["II","V"]], 1
   i               #     if that is the case:
     ðý            #       join inner pairs with spaces                           ["IV I","II V"]
       „, ý        #       join by ", "                                           "IV I, II V"
           ,       #       and print
```

---

With some optimization we can find all of them reasonably fast:

```
16EN¸2Å2«4Å1«Ý.«â€˜DONQÏεŽ6ˆ.XRøʒ¬Ā}D.X©JJ{sε`×}J{Qi®ðý„, ý,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWwAk/9vc2FiaWX//zE2RU7CuDLDhTLCqzTDhTHCq8OdLsKrw6LigqzLnERPTlHDj861xb02y4YuWFLDuMqSwqzEgH1ELljCqUpKe3POtWDDl31Ke1Fpwq7DsMO94oCeLCDDvSz///8tLW5vLWxhenk)

Comment: ``D.X©S{sε`×}S{Qi®`` to ``©.XDS{®ø`×S{Qi`` for -2

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 785 bytes:

```
import itertools as i
d={'I':1,'II':2,'III':3,'IV':4,'V':5,'VI':6,'VII':7,'VIII':8,'IX':9,'X':10,'XI':11,'XII':12,'XIII':13,'XIV':14,'XV':15,'XVI':16,'XVII':17,'XVIII':18,'XIX':19,'XX':20,'XXI':21,'XXII':22,'XXIII':23,'XXIV':24,'XXV':25,'XXVI':26,'XXVII':27,'XXVIII':28,'XXIX':29,'XXX':30,'XXXI':31,'XXXII':32,'XXXIII':33,'XXXIV':34,'XXXV':35,'XXXVI':36,'XXXVII':37,'XXXVIII':38,'XXXIX':39,'XL':40}
q=lambda p,s:all(d[a]==s.count(b)for a,b in p)and all(any(m==j for _,m in p)for b,_ in p for j in b)
def g(s):
 k=[1 if not(m:=max(h.count(i)for h in d))else sum([m]*len(s))for i in s]
 yield from i.product(*[[j for j in d if d[j]<=a]for a in k])
f=lambda s:{n for b in range(1,len(s)+1)for m in i.combinations(s,b)for j in g(m)if q(u:=[*zip(j,m)],(n:=','.join(a+' '+b for a, b in u)))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZJBj5swEIXv/ArfbCdWtECTUFSf2stK22sViaKVWSAxi20WE6npan97OmOz6sXvs8fzHmMx3ZaLs3kxzfe7NpObF6KXbl6cGz1Rnuikle/0kZapoI8gGQpoDvqLll8EhXUPK5wdUECPQQEKuHSi5VdBYU0fQNAoRUXIAiDlSGCUgt8JdY@KlUMApGMkxAKvoyU6g2Zojd5ZGgApi4SYBwTbDO3RP9sHwOIhEuJxReQi9KB3yADIQwim5GkkxGxF5Dwy@OchCJPyfSSsH1ZEPn4yborYiCGY9gTv@vCRvMlRmaZVZBK@VOPI2krVUvrdi7vahTW8dzNRoiHakokr2xK8pOyNGSkHgtVnYWIVN414DptQGRAbnrRdT87M8zIhr7JKie6JdQszpTTqD7usWToYXLCn5bwbfUf81bDK1Juxs9Ae6hrrvk7ITXdjS/rZQfpuml17fVnYpqqG/9EtJrXVUH@Tqg6D4OlrzZP@c2xfvtvQECaclT13LBUxb5uGxDCdho80jbZq0c565kV8mRBzZoZD0Bu7lrLa/NUTG4ThtWC2lFTQ3eC0ZWpLCd02JL5njLtyzj/u06xhevrbrjd7Bn/96en7j58U6vd/)

Code is able to crunch the reflexicons in about 0.4 seconds. The crux of the logic is, for every character in the "base" Roman numeral input (i.e `IV`, `IVX`, `VXMC`, etc) is first to find the maximum number of times that character can occur (e.g `I` occurs a maximum of `3` times, while `M` does not occur), take the maximum (if the letter does not occur, set maximum to `1`), and then multiply the maximum by the length of the base input, thus producing an upper bound for the range of each Roman numeral, drastically reducing the total number of Cartesian Products that have to be produced.

I am sure this solution can be golfed further - the Roman numeral lookup table takes up an incredible amount of space.

Comment: You don't need any roman numerals over 9.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 162 bytes

The strict output format prompted me to try a [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) approach. This is based on the output of [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239819/58563).

This is obviously very fast, and I think it's rather competitive (size-wise) compared to some code that would actually compute the strings.

```javascript
_=>`IV I, II V${"XLXCLCXDLDCDXMLMCMDM".replace(/../g,a=>[i=`
V`,0,0,0].map(n=>i+" I, II V0"+a[i+='I',0]+0+a[1]).join``)}
IX I0V, II X0L0C0D0M`.split`0`.join`, I `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxBCoMwFATQvacIUlDRxt8DxE2yCSRbCYj0B6sSsUZUuik9u7UtZVbDPGawD7s2i5u38@Rv7d6x/coKlCWRGZGSlKdnaJThihuhBBdGK8210CFd2nm0TRvnlOZ9ZllROYZBiRl8UtO7neOJFS4N/1cQprZyKYtkdIAUjnapEzp4NyEmr0AaIqH8WgMKOAjQSNd5dBsC/tyxEtwbP61@bOno@7iLk2R/Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>136</s> 135 bytes

```
Pick[StringRiffle[s=Pick[{RomanNumeral@#,d=Characters@"IVXLCDM"},Sign@#,1],","," "],StringCount[""<>s,#]&/@d,#]&/@0~Range~9~Tuples~7
```

Searches \$10^7\$ possibilities, so quite slow. Does not finish in a reasonable time. 
Check with better upper bounds on character occurences: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2T7PyAzOTs6uKQoMy89KDMtLSc1utgWLFYdlJ@bmOdXmptalJjjoKyTYuuckViUmFySWlTsoOQZFuHj7OKrVPu@v10nODM9D6jCMFZHCQQVlGJ1ICY655fmlUQrKdnYFesox6rpO6RAqJDSgpzU4miDuqDEvPTUumpLHSMgNITA2tj/AUDNJfoORf8B)

Includes the empty string containing zero symbols.

Any single roman numeral contains at most one (each) `VLD`, and at most three (each) `IXCM`.
Thus there are at most 8 (each) `VLD` (7*1+1), and at most 22 (each) `IXCM` (7*3+1). But the maximum possible number of any symbol is only 22, so `LCDM` can only occur at most once each, as "dummy text".

From here we can just run the program and see what the maximum encountered values of `IVX` are. Their maximum counts are 9, 2, and 2, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 149 bytes

```scala
"IV I,II V\nIX I,I V,II X,I L,I C,I D,I M"+{for{i<-0 to 3;j<-"DMCMCDLMLDLCXMXDXCXL"grouped 2}yield s"\nV${"I"*i} I,II V"+j.flatMap(",I "+_)}.mkString
```

By the findings of others here, we know already that there are exactly 42 (sic!) valid reflexicons. So one solution strategy is to generate these 42 lines by as small as possible code.
While doing so, I realized that my solution became very similar to [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239850/74778). However, his trick of further saving some bytes by temporarily substituting the multiple occurences of `,I`  via `0` does not seem to save additional bytes in the Scala approach taken here.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZNBS8MwFMfv@xSPIGx1rojedDtIukMgZdBJyWEgdU1HZ5bUNspk9LPXqNvcyNND4PXf95Lf7/CaZaayzjyv5dJCYjaZTmSh5LZcGt2A3Fqp8wYeqgp2PYD3TMFKallnVuZ3MLd1qVcw6QhLgV0xBulCM/FVQvr1KVzB3aHuRO7EZLgrTL0rx6NrsAZu79fjEYliGtOIxzziVMQiElRwsqrNWyVzuGk/SqlyaMhCpxc7wshl2e4fI8N1WKjMxlk1IO56MnwK2nDz8sPV7YHltnJy7qoJnHIeqgPaWULRJDpLuNfD0R56lghvSnhTAp3iLmE@NPOpmY/NfG7mgzOfnPnozGdnPjxD6DF8jB8TwAwwBcwBk8AsMA3UAxVBTVAV1AWVQW1QHdQHFfKN/t/Znlukym2UVXpw3P7gJCwL@P0RNpUq7aC/0P0gtGYuX8PG1N/7Nznu4p9NARA6S5IpfSQgVSOBTJNklpCg13af)